# The meaning of a line: you'd Chuck the whole sorry lot of them

Tags: meaning, phrases

It's the word from Insp. Japp in *ABC Murder*，when Hercule Poirot talked about the letters from abc.

> Now, if you were busy, you'd see these for what they are--nasty, cruel people, and some mad bloke playing a vicious game with you, and you'd Chuck the whole sorry lot of them.

What confused me was the meaning of this line: **you'd Chuck the whole sorry lot of them**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure "***Chuck***" is capitalized?
When capitalized "***Chuck***" is a person's name, short for "***Charles***",
when not capitalized "***chuck***" has the meaning "***to throw out***", "***to throw away***".

So your line has the meaning

> you'd **throw** the whole sorry lot of them **out**

The author is baasically saying, you would realize these are unfavorable / undesirable people and you'd get rid of them.